How to create custom data source reader in pyspark 3?
I want to create a custom reader to read data from a source not supported by pyspark as a POC for future use cases.
I came across a databricks article where they have used a datasource.py module for custom data source reader but I found its only supported in databricks not in general pyspark.
Could anyone share me a sample if successfully implemented.
